# how to add custom javascript to wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I currently need to add some custom jQuery to my wordpress functions, i have added jQuery the following way:

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

I need to add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".infobfn").append('<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="<?php echo $variable; ?>"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i></a>');});
```

The problem i have is that i cant add this to an external .js file as it contains php variables.

With it left in my functions i get the following:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

I have added ob_start(); which was recommended. I though this worked, but then realised only half of my page had loaded.

i am currently not using php header within my functions.php and have also checked for white space.

Any ideas how i can get around this?

Comment: Have you added an ob_start()?

Comment: Are you after guessed answers by leaving out your actual PHP code and the complete error message? Where did you read `ob_flush()` would help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: @Anigel - sorry i meant ob_start();

Comment: @mario - i added this at the very top of the functions.php

Comment: @mario how is this a duplicate? it's a different scenario....

Comment: `functions.php` is for Wordpress code, not folding in Javascript snippets. Consider the templates, where your HTML output resides. Also consider actually reading the link.

Comment: so if im creating a function in the functions.php your telling me to add js in my theme template?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you're doing wrong:

1. Dequeuing WP bundled jQuery

   - [Don’t Dequeue WordPress’ jQuery](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/)
   - [Why Loading Your Own jQuery is Irresponsible](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/)
2. Using jQuery without `noConflict` mode. The following example is the proper way to do it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    // Now, $ will refer to jQuery
    // Write all your logic inside this block
});
```

---

And, to solve the use of PHP variables inside your Javascript file, use [**`wp_localize_script`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). This function will pass any variables you want to a properly enqueued Javascript file.

Check [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498029/1287812) for a working example.